# Picard CollectGcBiasMetrics ignoring certain chromosomes/sequences

Tags: sam, picard

What's the easiest way to run Picard GCBias ignoring certain chromosomes/sequences in the reference? Looking at the CollectGcBiasMetrics, it seems there isn't a bed file option that can be passed.

```
java -jar ~/picard-tools-1.134/picard.jar CollectGcBiasMetrics --help
USAGE: CollectGcBiasMetrics [options]

Documentation: http://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/command-line-overview.html#CollectGcBiasMetrics

Tool to collect information about GC bias in the reads in a given BAM file. Computes the number of windows (of size specified by WINDOW_SIZE) in the genome at each GC% and counts the number of read starts in each GC bin.  What is output and plotted is the "normalized coverage" in each bin - i.e. the number of reads per window normalized to the average number of reads per window across the whole genome..

Version: 1.134(a7a08c474e4d99346eec7a9956a8fe71943b5d80_1434033355)


Options:

--help
-h                            Displays options specific to this tool.

--stdhelp
-H                            Displays options specific to this tool AND options common to all Picard command line 
                              tools.

--version                     Displays program version.

CHART_OUTPUT=File
CHART=File                    The PDF file to render the chart to.  Required. 

SUMMARY_OUTPUT=File
S=File                        The text file to write summary metrics to.  Default value: null. 

WINDOW_SIZE=Integer           The size of windows on the genome that are used to bin reads.  Default value: 100. This 
                              option can be set to 'null' to clear the default value. 

MINIMUM_GENOME_FRACTION=DoubleFor summary metrics, exclude GC windows that include less than this fraction of the 
                              genome.  Default value: 1.0E-5. This option can be set to 'null' to clear the default 
                              value. 

IS_BISULFITE_SEQUENCED=Boolean
BS=Boolean                    Whether the SAM or BAM file consists of bisulfite sequenced reads.  Default value: false. 
                              This option can be set to 'null' to clear the default value. Possible values: {true, 
                              false} 

METRIC_ACCUMULATION_LEVEL=MetricAccumulationLevel
LEVEL=MetricAccumulationLevel The level(s) at which to accumulate metrics.  Default value: [ALL_READS]. This option can 
                              be set to 'null' to clear the default value. Possible values: {ALL_READS, SAMPLE, 
                              LIBRARY, READ_GROUP} This option may be specified 0 or more times. This option can be set 
                              to 'null' to clear the default list. 

INPUT=File
I=File                        Input SAM or BAM file.  Required. 

OUTPUT=File
O=File                        File to write the output to.  Required. 

ASSUME_SORTED=Boolean
AS=Boolean                    If true (default), then the sort order in the header file will be ignored.  Default 
                              value: true. This option can be set to 'null' to clear the default value. Possible 
                              values: {true, false} 

STOP_AFTER=Long               Stop after processing N reads, mainly for debugging.  Default value: 0. This option can 
                              be set to 'null' to clear the default value.
```

Given this, and wanting to calculate GCBias the using Picard (not other software), what's the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is to use a different tool (some of this you could do with `computeGCBias` in deepTools). But since you don't want to do that, you'll have to manually remove unwanted chromosomes from the BAM file(s):

```
$ cat foo.awk
BEGIN{split(excludes, excludeList, " ")}
{exclude=0
if($1 == "@SQ") {
    for(ex in excludeList) {
        if(ex == substr($2, 4)) {
            exclude=1
            break
        }
    }
} else { \
    for(ex in excludeList) {
        if(ex == $3) {
            exclude=1
            break
        }
    }
}
if(!exclude) print}

$ excludes="chr1 chr2"
$ samtools view -h alignments.bam | awk -v excludes="$excludes" -f foo.awk | samtools -bo alignments.filtered.bam
```

The awk script is stripping unwanted chromosomes from the header and the body. You can then run the result through picard.